# wget recursion assistance

Tags: wget

I am attempting to download all the pdfs from a directory on a website with the following:

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.pdf http://www.eduplace.com/math/mw/practice/1/practice/
```

However, I keep getting "ERROR 404: Not Found". This seems like a pretty straight forwards usage and I'm at a loss on what to try next.

Comment: Lucky man! I got 403. You may should login to the site to access it.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the PDFs being served with CGI and I need to use the '--referer=url' option.  Could still use some help....

Comment: There should be a link where all links to the pdfs are listed. The one you are using does not list any pdf. So how should wget find them?

Comment: @rudimeier That is what the -r is for....recursion. If I had a list of paths to each PDF I would just be using curl.

Comment: But wget can only find pdfs if it finds links to pdfs. The URL you are using gives an error. No pdfs are reachable from there. It works if you are using an existing URL and no -l1, for example ```wget -r --no-parent -A.pdf http://www.eduplace.com/math/mthexp/g2/index.html```

Comment: @rudimeier I see what you are saying. So does that mean that there is no way for wget to grab all the pdfs served from http://www.eduplace.com/math/mw/practice/1/lp_1_u1sel.html short of having a list a every path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wget -r can only work if all links to the pdfs are somehow reachable from the given URL.

What you could do is to "look" at the html source of the particular site http://eduplace.com/math/mw/practice/1/lp_1_u1sel.html to see how all the pdf links are constructed. Then write a small script to do that automatically, like this:

```
wget http://eduplace.com/math/mw/practice/1/lp_1_u1sel.html
CHAPT=$(grep chapter  lp_1_u1sel.html | sed 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/')
FEAT=$(grep feature  lp_1_u1sel.html | sed 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/')
for c in $CHAPT; do
    for f in $FEAT; do
        wget -O mw-practice-1-$c-$f.pdf https://www.eduplace.com/math/mw/practice/1/$c/$f.pdf
    done
done
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Thanks for showing me how to take wget to the next level!